# SQL- Cumulative sum based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario in which I have to calculate the counter based on below data.  If the status is A, B,C than counter should be 0 which is working fine.

If STATUS is D counter should do a cumulative sum with the exception that if status is changed in between(like in 201907) , the counter should reset again and sum should start again with 1,2,3 and so on. Any possible help is appreciated on same.

Input - 3 columns - Customer_No, Date, Status

```
CUSTOMER_NO Date        STATUS  
1234        201901          A   
1234        201902          B   
1234        201903          C   
1234        201904          D   
1234        201905          D   
1234        201906          D   
1234        201907          C   
1234        201908          D   
1234        201910          D   
1234        201911          D   
1234        201912          D
```

expected Output - Input columns + Counter Column

```
CUSTOMER_NO     Date     STATUS  COUNTER
----------------------------------------
1234            201901      A       0
1234            201902      B       0
1234            201903      C       0
1234            201904      D       1
1234            201905      D       2
1234            201906      D       3
1234            201907      C       0
1234            201908      D       1
1234            201910      D       2
1234            201911      D       3
1234            201912      D       4
```

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzPza.png)

Thanks

Comment: Your question depends on an ordering of the columns, but you have not specified an ordering.

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: If you're data doesn't contain some kind of always ascending key, this is impossible to achieve.

Comment: Apologies, data has a key column as well. Its year month format like 201901, 201902,201903, 201904 n so on for 12 records. output is the Counter column and it should reset the sum if the status changes to D - as shown in the image.

Comment: @ankurnagpal It would be more helpful if you edit the question and provide the more context regarding the expected output and the revised input as you are saying all in the text format.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of a gaps-and-islands problem.  For this particular incarnation, you can identify the islands by counting the number of non-D statuses before a given row.

After identifying the groups, use `case` and `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 'D'
             then row_number() over (partition by customer_no, grp, status order by date)
             else 0
        end) as counter
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status <> 'D' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer_no order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar approach this Gordon's, however, uses CTEs and `ROW_NUMBER` to make the islands first, and then 0's if there is only 1 row in that island using a windowed `COUNT` and a `CASE` expression:

```
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT ID,
           CUSTOMER_NO,
           [STATUS],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_NO ORDER BY ID) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_NO, [STATUS] ORDER BY ID) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(1,1234,'A'),
                (2,1234,'B'),
                (3,1234,'C'),
                (4,1234,'D'),
                (5,1234,'D'),
                (6,1234,'D'),
                (7,1234,'C'),
                (8,1234,'D'),
                (9,1234,'D'),
                (10,1234,'D'),
                (11,1234,'D'))V(ID,CUSTOMER_NO,[STATUS]))
SELECT ID,
       CUSTOMER_NO,
       [STATUS],
       Grp,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_NO, [STATUS], Grp) = 1 THEN 0
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_NO, [STATUS], Grp ORDER BY ID) - 1
       END AS [COUNTER]
FROM Grps;
```

As Gordon mentioned, as well, if you don't have some kind of sequential ID/Key, you can't do this with your data. You will need to implement some kind of sequential ID, and *hope* that your data retains it's "insert order".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a numbering like a serial number for the ordering purpose using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function as shown below.

```
create table SampleData(CUSTOMER_NO int
 , STATUS char(1)
 , COUNTER int)

insert into SampleData Values
(1234, 'A', 0),
(1234, 'B', 0),
(1234, 'C', 0),
(1234, 'D', 1),
(1234, 'D', 2),
(1234, 'D', 3),
(1234, 'C', 0),
(1234, 'D', 1),
(1234, 'D', 2),
(1234, 'D', 3),
(1234, 'D', 4)

;with cte as(  
  Select *  
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN  
  from SampleData  
)  
select CUSTOMER_NO  
 , STATUS  
 , COUNTER  
 , (SELECT SUM(case STATUS when 'D' then Counter else 0 end) FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.RN <= cte.RN) AS Needed  
from cte
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f669cf081ae7052732a267ddb85623b2) demo.

Comment: I really don't trust that `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN `. It makes no guarentee that it'll follow the order that the OP gives us, and therefore could easily give the wrong results.

Comment: @Larnu That is true but ultimately you have to use something if a value is not defined by OP for the ordering like `customer number`, `status` or the `counter`.

Comment: Yes, and if the OP doesn't have somethign to order by, then quite simply, they can't achieve what they want; not reliably anyway. This could easily return a different result set each time it is run.